# Why does this PHP PDO function not return the value from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, web

I have a web application which accepts an Excel spreadsheet, parses the data, and adds that data to a MySQL database. Some of the sheets are fine, everything works as expected. However some sheets are not returning `true` when they should. Before data is entered I have a general purpose function which will check that table for the value and then return `true` or `false`. This function looks like this:

```
//Check if a sql will return with any values
function tableCheck($table, $column, $value){
  //PDO Connecttion
  $core = Core::getInstance();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column = :value;";

  //Create a prepared statement
  $stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $stmt->execute();

  //return true if there is a hit on that value
  if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Like I said this works some of the time and some of the time it doesn't and I get tons of repeated values from that sheet. Obviously this seriously messes with my data.

At first I thought it had to do with special characters but I have since found sheets where this field does not have special characters have a similar problem. This problem only occurs on a single column as well. Other fields of the sheet parse perfectly fine in all cases.

Any idea on what could be causing this problem?

EDIT: I also want to note that if i copy/paste the data into MySQL workbench or the command line it does return the rows.

Comment: there is an important note about `->rowCount()` regarding the `SELECT` statement in the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @Ghost that is very interesting but since it works most of the time shouldn't I be okay for this particular database? It says "some databases" so if it works in general am I okay?

Comment: Yes, looks like you're using MySQL which will work fine

Comment: @eignhpants you might as well, just like in the manual use an alternative `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total`, something in the likes of that to get a reliable value

Comment: @Ghost yes this is a good point and I will add that to my todo list.

Comment: @Ghost i'm not sure I understand how to check without `rowCount()`.  All of the PDOStatement methods return objects or resultsets. I used rowCount() because it seemed like the solution closest to a true/false statement.

Answer (score 1):

This looks dangerous, but I'm sure you're doing some sort of filtering, right? :)

Sounds to me like some of your table or column names could be [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), for example `AS` and `BY`.

Put ticks around them in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = :value;";
```

Comment: None of the tables or columns are reserved words. What specifically do you mean by "This looks dangerous"? You mean SQL injection? My understanding was the use of prepared statements protected against this. Also what specifically do you mean by filtering. Obviously I am not an expert at this. I built this whole app by the seat of my pants basically.

Comment: Prepared statements won't protect you if a user can determine the value of `$column`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the data being entered was larger than the field would accept. The column was a VARCHAR and the incoming data was greater than 255 characters. I switched to a TEXT data type and the problem was solved.